# Getting $_POST values from array of input elements

Tags: php

I have an array of inputs similar to below

```
<input name="attr[]" value = "a" type="text" />
<input name="attr[]" value = "b" type="text" />
<input name="attr[]" value = "c" type="text" />
```

On the server side I am using a foreach loop to fetch the value entered. However, I want the values a ,b and c as well. How do i do that in PHP?

I did something like this but its not working for me. The `$key` returned is just an index.

```
foreach($_POST['attr'] as $key=>$val)
{
   //process each $key and $val
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code for retrieving values

```
foreach($_POST['attr'] as $key=>$val)
{
   echo $val;
}
```